# Output frequency unstable in 555 oscillator

Tags: timer, stability, 555

I'm trying to make a simple astable NE555. The output frequency increasing alone. For example it start from for example 4.2 kHz and immediately change to 4.3 kHz, 4.6 kHz, 5kHz, then play around 4.5 kHz up and down.

I tried different NE555 IC like TLC555 and a different 9V battery, same problem.

I am using breadboard.

[image: Schematic of the basic 555 oscillator circuit]

C1 is a ceramic capacitor. I measured the frequency using a PIC microcontroller based frequency counter.

Comment: What type of capacitor are you using for C1?

Comment: How are you measuring frequency?

Comment: Try changing R2 to 15k and C1 to 10nF  (4.6kHz)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  i am using ceramic capacitor..thanks

Comment: @Andyaka  i am using pic based frequency counter

Comment: @JImDearden  ok i will try

Comment: It's depending on the quality of the capacitor C1 and the resistors R1 and R2. If you choose low cost capacitor C1 with  +/-20% of Tolerance, the output frequency will be less accurate. More the capacitor has a better quality, more your frequency will be accurate.

Comment: use a polyester film capacitor for good results.  multilayer ceramic capacitors are typically very bad.

Answer (score 3):

### And this is why Class II ceramics make lousy timing caps

What you have discovered is one of the major application limits of what are known as Class II ceramic capacitors -- they can't be used for timing.  This is because the dielectrics used vary in dielectric constant, and thus the capacitor varies in capacitance, as the *voltage across the capacitor* changes -- this effect is known as voltage coefficient, or just voltco for short, and is the main reason for voltage derating of these capacitors in their application domain as well.

### How do you identify a Class II ceramic?  And what do you use instead?

Class II ceramics are easy to identify from their temperature coefficient rating -- all X?? (such as X7R and X5R) ceramics are Class II, while C0G (NP0) ceramics are Class I, i.e. temperature and voltage stable.  However, C0G capacitors are not available for values greater than 10nF as a practical matter, so for larger values, film caps (polyester/Mylar, polypropylene) are used instead when capacitance stability with voltage is a concern.

Answer (score 3):

First, you **must** have a bypass capacitor across the 555 power pins, especially for the non-CMOS type. 100uF/10V is good. The 555 derives its switching thresholds with a resistive divider from the power supply and any noise (internally or externally caused) during the cycle will change the timing. Use a 'clean' power supply with low impedance, such as from a dedicated regulator. It has a low voltage coefficient with *static* voltage changes, but not if it's bouncing around during the cycle. There is also the voltage coefficient issue which @ThreePhase points out, which will mostly lead to non-ideal waveforms but will change the timing if the supply voltage changes.

Secondly, the X7R type caps have a fairly large temperature coefficient so small changes in temperature can lead to timing changes (graph from [here](http://www.niccomp.com/help/eia-tc-codes.asp)).

[image]

As you can see, a 1°C change can lead to almost 0.1% change in frequency.

Comment: the capacitor on pin5 (which connects to the internal divider at 2/3VCC) proctect the thresholds against supply ripple. Unless it's extreme VCC ripple should not adversely effect operation.

Comment: @Jasen  Calculate the time constant and compare with the period.

Answer (score 1):

This might be way too late for you.

There is a capacitor missing in your circuit - there *should* be, *at least*, 100nF over from #1 to #4/#8. The 555 has a quirk in which it consumes *lots* of mA when switching its output. The internal resistance of the 9V battery can't cope with that. Better is putting a 10uF in parallel with 100nF, near the 555.